# Why does my hair particles look so thick in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I exported a genesis 8 female character as .fbx to blender bald. So I decided to create hair for my character in blender but it's looking very bad in cycles. I'm using blender 2.92. I've tried everything I could but I don't seem to find the solution. Please help guys.

Comment: maybe try to add a screenshot, because "very bad" is for me too general word to understand your problem :)

Comment: I can't even upload the pictures, it says upload error everytime. I'm new to this site.

Comment: You can upload images up to 2 MB in size. Save them in JPEG file format and they are small enough to upload. In contrast, the PNG file format, for example, creates larger files that can be too big to upload.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably the ***Hair Shape*** settings that are set too high (default values) and it looks like this:

[image: fat hair in Cycles]

To better see what's going on, go to **Eevee**, and set the ***Hair → Hair Shape Type*** to `Strip`. This gives you a better idea in Material Preview/Look Dev mode of how the hair actually looks like when it's rendered in **Cycles**. The hair particles now will look thick. Don't worry, we will fix it in a moment. Switch back to **Cycles**.

[image: fat hair in Eevee]

**Let's make the hair thinner:**  In the ***Hair Particles → Hair Shape*** settings you can adjust the thickness. Go to *Hair Shape* section, and try these values (for example): ***Strand Shape***: `-0.850`,  ***Diameter Root***: `0.05 m`, ***Tip***: `0.03 m`.

These values works best when your model is in real-world size and the **scale is applied** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

[image: final result]

Comment: This works for me! Thanks! I look for a way to make nice fiber strands for the coconut (the inside core part in brown)