# Hair Particle Issue

Tags: particles, hair

This is how my eyebrow looks like in the Material Preview:

[image]

but when i switch to the Render Preview it looks like this:

[image]
[image]

What could have happened here?

Comment: My guess is that you need to increase the number of light bounces for transparency. The default is 8 but this not enough when you have a lot of stacked transparent faces. It's the setting in *Render Properties* tab (Cycles) *> Light Paths > Max Bounces > Transparent*

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :/

Comment: Can you share a file with the eyebrow? You can upload it to https://pasteall.org/blend/ . After the upload post the new URL address here. It's the key to access the file.

Comment: I've just updated my post

Comment: Oh, this question is about hair particles. For some reason, I thought it was about hair cards. Silly me. The fix is simple. You just need to lower the thickness of the *Diameter Root* in the *Hair Shape* settings then it will look nice. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/210725/107598. Just another thing, the normals of the head are flipped (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598). This can cause shading issues. Go to edit mode, select everything and flip them with the Alt+N menu.

Comment: Yes! It solves the problem :) Thank you a lot