# hair balding when i render it

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

first time try to make hair, i watch from tutor in youtube is kinda simple so i tried.
when look in viewport is looks good for me but when i render.
it looks balding

viewport shading

[image: viewport shading]

sample render

[image]

here is my blend: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ncxZb3nHmK_61vQGB80oq7fm-OeDmUne/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference comes from the fact that hair diameter is hadled differently between Eevee and Cycles, and Viewport rendering is Eevee based.

In Cycles you can set the scale of the diamater in the Hair Shape tab of every particle system, so a quick solution is to alter this value as I did in the left side of my example.

For a solid workflow you should Apply Rot and Scale (Ctrl A) before using particle systems or any other function and modifier that relates to real world measures: in your case the 0.008 scale makes troublesome to use default values on the particle hair system, but if you Apply scale now, you will have to rework your hair particles from scratch.

[image]

Comment: I could save the edit. Just hit the *Disconnect Hair* button first to disconnect both hair systems, then apply *Rotation* and *Scale* to the head, and finally *Connect Hair* again. Also, make sure you set *Eevee > Curves > Shape* to `Strip` as described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210751/107598. Note: The *Hair > Hair Shape Type* option is renamed to *Curves > Shape* in Blender 3.1 and later.

Comment: Thank you Blunder for the interesting information!

Comment: thank you its really helpful for me